# Why do I need to manually enable laptop special keys in openbox

Tags: openbox

In order to enable the Mute, Volume up and Volume down keys in a fresh installation of `openbox`, one needs to follow the very simple [instructions](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Openbox:_Control_Speaker_Volume_Using_the_Keyboard_%28ALSA%29) from the official documentation. On several forum boards, people struggle with alternative procedures, most involving `showkey -k` and then hardcoding the key values into `~/.config/openbox/autostart`.

Why is all this hassle necessary, instead of being enabled by default, like the the brightness control?